# Azure durable function orchestration client cannot be found when the DurableTask nuget package is upgraded to version 2.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Have a queue-triggered function defined as the following example:

```
public async Task OrchestratorAsync(
            [QueueTrigger("my-queue", Connection = "")]string payload,
            [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient orchestrationClient)
        {
            //Do something
        }
```

The csproj file looks like the following details and it compiles successfully:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
  </ItemGroup>
</project>
```

When I upgrade `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` to version 2.0.0 the compiler throws error on not being able to find OrchestrationClient and DurableOrchestrationClient. So we're stuck with version 1.8.2! What's the solution for this issue?

Note: This issue is quite reproducible by VS 2019. Have it scaffold a Function project, the create another function as a durable orchestrator, tweak the csproj file and bump up the DurableTask nuget package version to 2.0.0 from the default 1.8.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have reproduce your error, and I solved this problem.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _11111fc
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient orchestrationClient)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "London"));

            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_Hello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")]HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient]IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

Change [OrchestrationClient] to [DurableClient]. Have a look of [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/releases).
Please take care of the breaking changes in `Durable Functions v2.0.0-beta2 Release`, the `OrchestrationClient` has been renamed.

Things works fine on my side. Please have a try on your side.